# Ignore errors in sql files in VS 2012

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have ".sql" files in my VB.NET projects in Visual Studio 2012.

They are configured as:

```
Build Action = None
Copy to output Directory = Copy Always
```

When the file is open in the text editor in Visual Studio, I get compile errors.
When the file is closed, I don't get compile errors.

I don't want it to find errors in these files, because I don't want to prevent the project from successfully building.  These are basically just text files for me.

Any ideas on how to disable this?

(An example of an error would be `SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near '<'`, which makes sense because it IS invalid SQL, but is how I want it.)

Comment: when you say they are just text files..  if they are not used as anything else but notepads in your project they could be renamed to .txt.

Comment: From Visual Studio's perspective, I want them treated as text files.  But from the logic in my software, the file names and contents are used to generate parameterized queries to access a database.  It is an annoying coincidence that Visual Studio and I picked the ".sql" extension to mean something, and yeah I wished I used a different extension, back 8 years ago when I started doing this.  It seems Visual Studio is more aggressive with sql files now.  Not even sure that when I started this, that Visual Studio even associated them with anything.

Comment: I open Oracle *.sql files in VS 2010 or VS 2012, and I get the errors **SQL80001**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phantom errors, while annoying, will not prevent the project from successfully building. They will just cloud up the error list and make finding the real issues more difficult.  I know this does not address your core problem but it should at least get your project building!

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I didn't notice my other error in the cloud of these errors.  Well, still, it is annoying to have to see those.  But, I guess this won't stop me from building the projects.

Comment: I would like disabled those ***SQL80001*** errors. I open Oracle sql files in VS 2010 or VS 2012, and I get the errors.